# Option to create menu is missing

Tags: menus

I installed WordPress locally on WAMP server. I did also install Elementor plug-in. I don't find an option to create menu bar and add pages to the menu, anywhere. Do I need to create more pages for the option to be visible?

Comment: This is an Elementor question and should be asked via their forums and support.

Comment: That´s because you are using the twenty twenty-two theme or any theme with block edition capabilities, that option rely on completely on your theme, you need to change to another theme, if you are working with Elementor I recommend you to use the Hello Elementor Theme,it´s free an you could find it through the themes installer on Wordpress

Comment: Thanks Jose, I will try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @JoséAntonioPérez, Hi, I've a WordPress page built with DIVI builder that has multiple <title> tags as verified with its view source page. I don't find the <title> tag in the Divi builder's sections so I can remove the duplicates. Can you share your thoughts on locating the full HTML of this page https://andersonadvisors.com/how-to-structure-a-business-workshop-training/ in the WordPress admin or Divi builder?